# Bootstrap not working with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I´ve downloaded tweeter bootstrap (not the bootststrap for MVC) to a brand new MVC4 project, but I can´t make it work.

No errors in browser´s F12 window.

Here is my _layout code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      @RenderBody()
  </body>
</html>
```

When the screen pops up, I get a normal Hello, world! body (no bootstrap fonts). My system has the following files:

[image]

What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only included the `bootstrap-theme.min.css` file and not the base `bootstrap.css` file. (though you did include the `bootstrap.js` file)

Comment: Ups!!! That´s what 10 hours of coding does with your brains.... Thanks Andrew for that!